# Explanation of casting/conversion int/double in C#

Tags: c#, .net, casting, implicit-conversion

I coded some calculation stuff (I copied below a really simplifed example of what I did) like CASE2 and got bad results. Refactored the code like CASE1 and worked fine. I know there is an implicit cast in CASE 2, but not sure of the full reason. **Any one could explain me what´s exactly happening below?**

```
  //CASE 1, result 5.5
    double auxMedia = (5 + 6);
    auxMedia = auxMedia / 2;

    //CASE 2, result 5.0
    double auxMedia1 = (5 + 6) / 2;

    //CASE 3, result 5.5
    double auxMedia3 = (5.0 + 6.0) / 2.0;

    //CASE 4, result 5.5
    double auxMedia4 = (5 + 6) / 2.0;
```

My guess is that /2 in CASE2 is casting (5 + 6) to int and causing round of division to 5, then casted again to double and converted to 5.0.

CASE3 and CASE 4 also fixes the problem.

Comment: As a side note; there is only *one* operation done at runtime here. The `/2` in case 1. The rest is all done by the compiler.

Comment: @Marc: can't the compiler even perform case 1 entirely at compile-time, since `auxMedia` is local and assigned with a constant? Or is that an optimization that's left strictly to the JIT?

Comment: @Michael - I would *expect* that to be left to the JIT. To answer it you'd need to look at different compiler outputs...

Comment: @Marc - I guess I'm wondering if the C# spec might *forbid* an optimization like that for some reason. The C/C++ standards have the whole notion of the 'as if' rule, which causes confusion at times. I could see that the C# designers might want to bail on dealing with an 'as if' rule because they can punt those optimizations to the JIT/runtime. This is all just just rambling out of curiosity, with little or no real applicability (I think).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. 5 + 6 is integer 11; which you then cast to double (in the assignment) and divide by two; 5.5
2. 5 + 6 is integer 11; integer 11 / 2 = **5** under integer arithmetic, which you ***then*** cast to double (in the assignment)
3. 5.0 + 6.0 is double 11.0; divide by double 2.0 giving double 5.5
4. 5 + 6 is integer 11; there is an implicit cast to double 11.0 for the division, then divide double 2.0 giving double 5.5

Comment: Marc is correct. If your second line was was `auxMedia = auxMedia / 2.0` then you would get the result you expect since `2.0` is read as a double and `2` is read as an int (it drops off any decimal digits - doesn't even round).

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Marc's (correct) answer a bit, whole numbers are interpreted as integer, whereas numbers with decimal points are interpreted as double. To declare a whole number as a literal double, append a "D" to it:

```
        //CASE 2b, result 5.5
        double auxMedia2b = (5D + 6D) / 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//CASE 2, result 5.0
double auxMedia1 = (5 + 6) / 2;
```

The result of the (5 + 6) operation is integer. Because both operands are of type integer. Then, the compiler performs 11 / 2, where both operand are also integers. The result of the last division is obviously 5, because it is an integer division (don't know the proper English word).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. CASE 2 uses integer arithmetic until the assignment is made. You can also fix the problem by making an explicit cast:

```
double auxMedia1 = ((double) (5 + 6)) / 2;
```